# Как сделать функцию для реагирования на нажатие всюду, кроме элемента?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть страничка, и на ней кнопка. Если нажать на кнопку, то открывается окно подсказки. А если нажать в любое другое место на страничке, кроме этой кнопки и окна подсказки, то подсказка должна закрыться. Как это сделать? Открыть - нет проблем, а вот как задать функцию для закрытия?

Comment: @Helena2977, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В событие обычно передается информация о событии (event), из него можно достать информацию о том, на что пользователь кликнул.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if(event.target != someElement) {
        closeWindow();
    } 
});
```

Правда, тут надо еще учесть, что клик на вложенные в подсказку элементы тоже могут привести к закрытию.

Comment: Спасибо, а еще, может, подскажете, как на класс проверить?

Можно так: 

    if ($(event.target).hasClass("MyClass"))
___
А что значит `$(event.target).closest('.popup').length`?
_____
Почитала про closest. Кажется, поняла. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Helena2977, что-то мне подсказывает, что вы не туда пишите.

Answer (score 1):

Схематично:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.popup').length ||
        $(event.target).closest('.button').length) return;

    popup.hide();

    event.stopPropagation();
});
```